# How does new Facebook App integrates App Store page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, app-store

Since some weeks Facebook displays ads for apps in their iOS client. When you click on them the App Store apps detail page **opens as a modal view controller inside the Facebook app**.

I only know how do open App Store pages via their URL, but how to show a App Store page from inside your app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the SKStoreProductViewController. Here is a link to the docs :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html

I also found this helpful tutorial :)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class

Comment: Nice! Is there also something similar for music and other media? Or is this class already universal (documentation only mention apps)?

Comment: Ok, just read through the tutorial and they already answered my question. The class is useable for all kinds of media.

Comment: Yep Its pretty awesome :) TONS of sweet implications from selling Game soundtracks, to selling other apps, to selling companion iBooks for educational apps. Can't wait to see how you use it, Happy Coding :)